# Losing context from function returned by ternary operator

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I know how to get around this particular problem, but I would like to know why it happens. Basically, when I try to invoke a function like this:

```
(callFoo ? this.foo : this.bar)();
```

It calls the correct foo function, but inside of foo, `this` is the global, window object instead of the object I expect.

I would expect that this does the same thing but it does not:

```
(this.foo)();
```

The code above calls the right function and maintains the correct context (`this` is what I expect it to be).

[Here is a jsfiddle for you to play around with.](http://jsfiddle.net/lbstr/RKcMG/)

Could someone please explain what is going on? I understand how to get around the problem (I'm not even a fan of that syntax), but I still want to know why `this` becomes the window if you return a function from a ternary operator.

---

**EDIT**
I'd like to refine my question:
It makes sense to me that this:

```
(callFoo ? this.foo : this.bar)();
```

is equivalent to:

```
var f = (callFoo ? this.foo : this.bar);
f();
```

And it makes sense to me why `this` becomes the window within that function.

Why doesn't the same thing happen here:

```
(this.foo)();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason for the discrepancy:

```
var obj = new (function MyConstructor(){
    this.getConstructor = function(){ return this.constructor.name; }
});
```

When operands are operated on by any operator, the results work much like the return value of a function. An object method passed is no longer treated like it's tied to the object.

```
(function(){ return obj.getConstructor; })(); //'Window'
```

But in the case where nothing is happening inside the parens other than property access, the parens are simply ignored rather than treated as operators themselves. So:

```
(obj.getConstructor)(); //'MyConstructor'
```

Is really just equivalent to:

```
obj.getConstructor();
```

But add a valid operation of any kind resulting in the method:

```
(false || obj.getConstructor)(); //'Window'
```

And obj.getConstructor is treated as a method that's been passed rather than a method tied to an object via the '.' association.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. And thanks for correcting the `(+obj.getConstructor)()` bit. I was trying to think of something like that, but I couldn't.

Comment: Yeah, I shouldn't have assumed that would work just because it works with anon functions. One oddity is that native object methods don't necessarily follow the same behavior even though they behave as if they were using 'this' in other ways.

Answer (score 2):

To have the correct context-invocation object, call it like

```
this[ callFoo ? 'foo' : 'bar' ]();
```

The value of `this` always depends on *how* you invoke a function. You're basically calling the function just like

```
fnc();
```

which causes `this` always to be *global* / *window* (in non strict mode). You need to invoke the function as *method* / *property* like `this.fnc()`. In that case, `this` will refer to the object of invocation by default.

Comment: Thanks for the answer -- I like the comparison to `fnc()` because it makes it very clear that the context will be lost. As I said, I understand how to get around it, but I'm more curious why `(callFoo ? this.foo : this.bar)()` is different than `(this.foo)()`. Is `(this.foo)` just not evaluated? Making it identical to `this.foo`?

Answer (score 1):

This expression is logically equivalent to something like this:

```
var tempFun;
if(callFoo) {
    tempFun = this.foo;
} else {
    tempFun = this.bar;
}
tempFun();
```

Which is a classical example of loosing `this` reference. As you said, you know the workaround/solution:

```
tempFun.call(this);
```

or:

```
(callFoo ? this.foo : this.bar).call(this)
```

Comment: I liked how you broke it out into the actual if-else. It definitely helps clear things up. Any explanation as to why the same thing doesn't happen for `(this.foo)()`?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the ternary operator, you are selecting between two functions.  This would be similar to doing something like the following:

```
var func = this.foo;
foo(); // Inside this call, "this" will now refer to the global context
       // -- "window" in a browser environment
```

This (i.e., "this") is one of the big tricky things in JavaScript, and much has been written about it.

It is a bit of a surprise that the problem does not also occur when you throw parens around "this.foo".  But that was not your question :-)